# Start FTP Website from powershell 4

Tags: powershell, iis-7.5

Trying to automate ftp site manipulation on IIS7.5, through powershell, but I can't start the ftp site. Everything else, so far, I succeeded.

```
PS IIS:\Sites> Get-ChildItem | Where {$_.Name -eq "FtpData"}

Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings
----             --   -----      -------------                  --------
FtpData          3    Stopped    D:\Services\_Empty             ftp *:80:



PS IIS:\Sites> Start-WebSite -Name "FtpData"
Start-WebSite : The object identifier does not represent a valid object. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800710D8)
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-WebSite -Name "FtpData"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Website], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.StartWebsiteCommand
```

This issue is address in [technet "Starting / Stoping an FTP site using PowerShell... IIS 7.5 on 2008R2"](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4b3f0f61-750d-4554-9aac-38997d8daf84/starting-stoping-an-ftp-site-using-powershell-iis-75-on-2008r2?forum=winserverpowershell) but is has three years old.

Using the appcmd  has the same issue:

```
C:\Users\myself>c:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd start site FtpData
ERROR ( hresult:800710d8, message:Command execution failed.
The object identifier does not represent a valid object.
 )
```

This article [FTP on IIS 7 on Server Core](http://forums.iis.net/t/1157815.aspx?FTP+on+IIS+7+on+Server+Core) indicates to start it from the UI Console, but that means it can't be automated.

Has any one got a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled upon this through Powershell autocomplete and turned out working on Server 2012 R2:

```
    $ftpSite = IIS:\Sites\FtpData
    $ftpSite.ftpServer.Start()
```

Answer (score 0):

The $ftpSite... did not work for me.  I also found the below to be neater.

To Start:

```
 (get-Website -Name "myftpsite").ftpserver.start()
```

To Stop:

```
 (get-Website -Name "myftpsite").ftpserver.stop()
```

Source:  https://peter.hahndorf.eu/blog/iisftp.html
(Forever Breathes The Lonely Word - Peter Hahndorf on software
IIS - Managing FTP sites with PowerShell)

Comment: param (
...
    [string]ftpSite= "ftp-site"
)
(get-Website -Name $ftpSite).ftpserver.start()